# How to generate all possible combinations of values from n different sets?

Tags: combinatorics

I have n sets, each having n1,n2,n3...nN distinct members.
How do I generate n1*n2*n3...*nN possible combinations from them

e.g

```
[6] [4 5] [1 2 3 4]
will give
6 4 1 
6 4 2
6 4 3 
6 4 4
6 5 1 
6 5 2
6 5 3
6 5 4
```

I want to do this in matlab, but a normal algorithm would also be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for Cartesian product of sets:

This should help:

```
cartprod(N1,N2,N3, ...)
```

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5475-cartprod-cartesian-product-of-multiple-sets

There's another one [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064)

```
set = {n1, n2, n3, ...}
allcomb(set{:})
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is to simulate a sum !

Start with a list of indices 0 0 0, corresponding to the indices of your values. That leads you to the value 6 4 1 in your example.
then add 1.
You now have indices 001, so 642
and so on.

at 004, you overflow, so your indices become 010, having 6 5 1

Keep doing that, and keep a counter of the visited possibilites. There are 1 * 2 * 4 possibilities, so it's easy to know when you are done.